# What is Net::HTTP doing differently than executing curl in ruby?

Tags: ruby, curl, net-http

I have methods that GETs a resource from an external Rails server via JSON.  One uses the `net/http` library, the other executes `curl`.  They respond differently.

If I use `net/http`

```
def get_via_nethttp(endpoint, user, password, id)
  uri = URI.parse("#{endpoint}/items/#{id}.json")
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  headers = {
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip,deflate',
    'Accept' => 'application/json'
  }
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri, headers)
  request.basic_auth(user, password)

  http.request(request)
end
```

then the return code is ASCII-8Bit encoded.  Here's a snippet:

```
\x1F\x8B\b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\xBDWmo\xE28\x10\xFE+Vv\xA5...
```

However, if I use `curl`

```
def get_via_curl(endpoint, user, password, id)
  %x(curl -u #{user}:#{password} #{endpoint}/items/#{id}.json)
end
```

then a JSON string returns

```
"{\"id\":1234,\"title\":\"Foo\"}"
```

I've tried numerous ways to decode the output of `net/http` to no avail.  In the end, I just want the JSON string, so I ended up going with `curl`.  What's the difference that's causing this?

Comment: your headers different in curl and net/http I am guessing you are receiving a gzip binary with net/http and a json response from curl

Comment: remove `Accept-Encoding` header

Comment: @NARKOZ bjhaid That's it.  If one of you posts the answer I'll accept it.

So does this mean that the encoded response was gzip'ed?

Comment: It means that response was chunked encoded and since your client doesn't support compression, you don't need that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting in headers `'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip,deflate'` can result server sending you a chunked response. Just remove it.